# Android Studio, signed APK, unable to compute hash (proguard)

Tags: android-studio, android-proguard

Android Studio 1.3.1

I have the following files:

**%appname%\app\build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

  repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  } 
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
}
```

**%appname%\app\proguard-project.txt**

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.github.PhilJay.
-keep class com.github.PhilJay.** { *; }


-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
```

(**I have tried quite a few things here. Still learning to ensure everything is 100% correct**)

When I try generated a signed APK I get error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. Unable to
>   compute hash of
>   W:\android-studio-projects\%appname%\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar

Before that I get these two warnings:

> Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu: can't find referenced
>   class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy Warning:there were 3
>   unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
>            If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
>            the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
>   Exception while processing task

Now if I change to

```
minifyEnabled true
```

It works, but... I would prefer to use minify. I am not sure if the warnings are the reason? Afterall, it states the warnings can be suppresed, so those warnings are not necessarily the cause of the error?

Comment: I have added a lot more information now. I hope I won't get downvoted because I believe i have tried everything I could find online including on SO

Comment: i have same problem with Android Studio 1.4

Answer (score 1):

About hash generation problem, I had same problem when i try to generate a signed apk with minify and proguard enabled.

Notice that I'm sure the proguard config works, because i use it for the same project in Eclipse.

The workaround i found was to delete the project's .gradle (not the gradle!!) the  and all module's build directories.

Then i make a full rebuild.. and the apk is done.

I known that it is not the best solution.. but it works.